# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StaticPagesController#home

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error whenever I try to access the application. The error is about the application controller. This is the error.
Couldn't find all Private::Conversations with 'id': (17, 38) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2).

The error is explained more in the bash as follows
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Private::Conversations with 'id': (17, 38) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2).):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:28:in `opened_conversations_windows'
I have tried changing the find method but things do not seem to work with methods such as find_by.

```
def opened_conversations_windows


        if logged_in?

            # opened conversations

            session[:private_conversations] ||= []

            @private_conversations_windows = Private::Conversation.includes(:recipient, :messages)
                                              .find(session[:private_conversations])



          else

            @private_conversations_windows = []


        end
end
```

I expect that when no conversation is found, the app should render nil conversation windows when a user logs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is designed to raise an error if the record for the given id is not found.

If you do not want to raise an error then you can use `find_by` when you want to find a single record or return `nil` when that record doesn't exist. Or you can build a query with `where` which always returns an array of matching record on an empty array if there any matching records.

You can refactor your method to:

```
def opened_conversations_windows
  if logged_in? && session[:private_conversations]
    @private_conversations_windows = Private::Conversation
                                       .includes(:recipient, :messages)
                                       .where(id: session[:private_conversations])
  else
    @private_conversations_windows = []
  end
end
```